# Validations failed to work in PHP and Session

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, session

I have created an Online Marathon Form where it requires the user to fill in all the available fields prepare. Once it's done and submitted, the form will be validated to check any error with the submitted form. However, those validations I set didn't work except only `name` validation.
I tried to figure the cause for almost 3 days and kept asking people around but they didn't reply.
I hope anyone can help me solving this error : `Validations set failed to work`. I must need this `Session` for my work.

`pbt1.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['pbt1']))
{
    $nameError      =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['nameError'];  
    $numberError    =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['numberError'];
    $dateError      =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['dateError'];
    $addressError   =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['addressError'];
    $cityError      =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['cityError'];
}
?>

<style>
.registrationform 
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    border: solid 3px red;   
}

Label
{
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}

</style>

    <div class= "registrationform">

        <h1>ONLINE MARATHON REGISTRATION</h1>
        <br><br>

        <form name = "pbt1" method = "post" action = "validation.php">
        
        <Label>Name<span style="color: red;">*</span>: </Label>
        <input type = "text" name = "name">
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;" > <?php echo isset($nameError)?$nameError :'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <Label>Gender <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</Label> 
        <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Female">Female
        <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Male">Male
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($genderError)?$genderError :'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <Label>Date Of Birth <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</Label> 
        <input type = "date" name = "date">
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($dateError)?$dateError:'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <Label>Contact Number <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</Label> 
        <input type = "text" name = "phonenumber">
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($numberError)?$numberError:'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <Label>Address <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</Label>
        <input type = "text" name = "address" >
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($addressError)?$addressError :'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <Label>City <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</Label> 
        <input type = "text" name = "city" >
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($cityError)?$cityError:'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <Label>Zip Code <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</Label> 
        <input type = "text" name = "zipcode" >
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($zipcodeError)?$zipcodeError:'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" name="Submit">
        </div>
        </form>
        
    </div>

    <br><br>
</html>
```

`validation.php`

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if(isset($name) && empty($name))
    {
        $_SESSION['pbt1']['nameError']="Name must be required!";
        header('location: pbt1.php');  
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
        {
            $_SESSION['pbt1']['nameError'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            header('location: pbt1.php');  
            exit;
        }   
    }

    $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    if(isset($phonenumber) && empty($phonenumber))
        {
            $_SESSION['pbt1']['numberError'] = "Error, insert phone number";
            header('location: pbt1.php');  
            exit;
        }
    else 
        {
            if(!preg_match('/^([0-9]*)$/', $phonenumber))
            {
                $_SESSION['pbt1']['numberError'] = "Numbers only";
                header('location: pbt1.php');  
                exit;
            }
        }
    


    $_SESSION['Userdata'] = ['name'=>$name , 'phonenumber'=>$phonenumber,'address'=>$address,'city'=>$city,
                            'zipcode'=>$zipcode,'gender'=>$gender,'date'=>$date ];

    header("location:pbt2.php");
    exit;
}

function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

`pbt2.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<style>
    table 
{
    text-align:center;
}
</style>



<div style="background-color:cyan;">

<h1 align = 'center'> YOUR INFORMATION AS THE TABLE BELOW </h1>

<table width = '400' border = '1' align = 'center'>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['name'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone Number</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['phonenumber'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['address'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['city'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zip Code</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['zipcode'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['gender'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['date'];?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Nothing here would output `Validations set failed to work`. Please clarify error message(s) being received. You also don't need the `isset` and `empty` check for every variable, and likely are better to only have the `empty` check on the `$_POST` value. That would avoid notices. Additionally, regex probably should use `+` for quantifier to require something is entered.

Comment: `test_input` function is crap, use `filter_input()` to sanitize the input variables

Comment: @user3783243 Can you explain a bit more details and provide some examples  a bit?
@LarsStegelitz what `filter_input()` does usually?

Comment: Well specifically `test_input` is an attempt to resolve any injection issue but it just cause other issues down the road. Use the function(s) for the use you require, there isn't a one stop, fix everything function. All functions can be read about on php.net. By my comment I meant that nothing in this script would output `Validations set failed to work`. Please clarify what currently happens when you run the script

Comment: @user3783243 I added the picture there so I hope you can understand better what I mean

Comment: Is the question then why don't you get the other errors reported or something else? You need to be clearer with the question. The answer to the first question is `$_SESSION['pbt1']['nameError']="Name must be required!"; header('location: pbt1.php'); exit;`. You should run through the full validation to get all errors, then redirect if any error is present.

Comment: I thought people would understand that whatever validations I made didn't work at all and I need someone to show me which parts that caused the errors.

Comment: The notices/errors come from only setting the one index. The page displays the message for when the name is empty so I would guess that behavior is correct. Without a detailed description of the issue it will be hard to assist.